# Reference errors in ASP.NET 5 project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have created a new web project with **ASP.NET 5** preview templates in VS 2015. I am getting the below Reference errors in Solution Explorer. How to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Right Click on solution, go to properties and make sure that Target Framework is .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: @AramKocharyan I don't see "Target Framework", I see "Solution DNX SDK Version" with options 1.0.0-beta7 and1.0.0-beta5

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the errors by installing the below .msi files from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738

- DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
- WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi